# Mock a MDC data in spring boot test

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I want to mock a data which is fetched from MDC in test class other wise when the code executed it return a null value. So i try below,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest( webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,classes = TestApp.class)

public class Test {

    private MockMvc restMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mock(MDC.class);
        this.restMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(TestController).build();    
    }       
    
    @Test
    public void testMe() throws Exception {            
     when(MDC.get("correlation-id")).thenReturn("1234");    
     //Req param and header are intialized          
     restMvc.perform(get("/assignments").headers(headers).params(reqParams).principal(token).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());    
    }

}
```

But i am getting error,

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Comment: Why mock and not simply use the real MDC? `MDC.put("correlation-id", "1234")` and you're good to go.

Comment: @knittl yes this worked as well. btw i noticed running the test the interceptor preHandle is not invoked. any reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mock a static method you should use `Mockito.mockStatic` method like this:

```java
try (var mockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(MDC.class)) {
    mockStatic.when(() -> MDC.get("correlation-id"))
              .thenReturn("1234");

    // rest of the test...
}
```

You can read more about it [in the Mockito documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks). Additionally, I've reproduced the problem and tested the solution - you can see [a commit in a GitHub repository with all required code](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/commit/58106cfa1dd4ccd7dd7fdef04941897bd7f954f1). Please note that usage of `mockito-inline` is required for this to work - see [this part of the docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final).

---

In case of your test, it would probably better to go with the approach proposed by @knittl in the comment - instead of mocking the `get` method, a value can be set in the `MDC` using the `put` method: `MDC.put("correlation-id", "1234")`. I've included both approaches in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/commit/58106cfa1dd4ccd7dd7fdef04941897bd7f954f1) mentioned before - both tests pass.

Comment: just added above mockStatic before restMvc. perform but still seems when it hits the MDC.get it return null value

Comment: You'd have to include the code, it's hard to guess without it.

Comment: Well once i added restMvc.perform inside try block it worked. Any idea why it didnt work when perform call is outside try block

Comment: That's the way Mockito Inline works: the try-with-resources block defines the scope for which the mocking is applied. Anything outside it works as if the mock didn't exist. You can read more about it in the linked Mockito docs.

Comment: A separate issue i faced may be you could provide a clue, On same test class i would like to mock the service call which invoked from controller so i added below,       @Mock
MyService myService; And then Mock the result like this Mockito.when(myService.getAssignments(Mockito.any(AssignmentsRequestDTO.class))).thenReturn(assinment);  But when i run the test class it always go inside service class with out mock it. Any idea? I still have above RunWith and SpringBootTest
annotations shown in my question

Comment: Use @MockBean to let the mock be injected into the Spring context. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75162635/mock-results-in-exception-but-mockbean-works-in-spring-boot-application/75163319#75163319